# Using Blender & Python for Batch Image Conversion, getting unexplained Runtime Errors

Tags: python, file-format, conversion

I need to import a bunch of models which use .dds textures, which are not supported by Cycles, but they are supported by Blender. I can open such a .dds in the image editor, and press F3(Save image as) to save it as a perfectly functional .png file.

However when I try to do this through Python, it fails without a useful error message, and no new file gets created.

Here is my code:

```
# Set current panel to Image/UV Editor
area = bpy.context.area
area.type = 'IMAGE_EDITOR'

for i in bpy.data.images:
    area.spaces.active.image = i
    newPath = i.filepath.replace("dds", "png")
    bpy.ops.image.save_as(save_as_render=False, filepath=newPath, relative_path=True)
```

Which will throw this useless error:

```
Couldn't save picture.
D:\Path\FileName.png: No error
Error: Could not write image: No error
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\ProjectPath\TexConvertTest.blend\Text", line 19, in <module>
  File "C:\3D\Blender\blender-2.79-windows64\2.79\scripts\modules\bpy\ops.py", line 189, in __call__
    ret = op_call(self.idname_py(), None, kw)
RuntimeError: Error: Could not write image: No error
```

I tried running it with admin priviliges, but no difference. Any other suggestions would be appreciated!

Comment: Have you checked if i.filepath contains something useful? RenderResult and other internal images do not have any filepath, which has to be filtered out. Otherwise add a print statement to identify what image it fails on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use operators unless there is no other way. In this case you're making your life overly complicated with them. This is my proposed approach:

```
for i in bpy.data.images:
    new_path = i.filepath.replace(".dds", ".png")
    if new_path == i.filepath:
        print('Refusing to overwrite %s (name=%r)' % (i.filepath, i.name))
        continue
    i.save_render(bpy.path.abspath(new_path))
```

I've also taken the liberty to change a bit more:

- Replacing `.dds` instead of just `dds`. You don't want to change `adds-liquid.dds` into `apng-liquid.png`. For more reliable manipulating of file paths I would recommend [pathlib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html) rather than string manipulation.
- Using `bpy.path.abspath()` to convert any blendfile-relative file path to an absolute path. Without this, saving the file won't work reliably.
- Added a check to prevent overwriting a non-DDS file.
- Applied [PEP 8 -- Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) to your variable names.

Comment: Works like a charm, thank you so much! Both for the solution and the great advice.